# understanding the definition of a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a subset. We call $S$ a **regular surface** if there
exists for every point $p \in S$ an open neighbourhood $V$ of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and if, in addition, there exists an open subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and a smooth map $F :U \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that
(i) $F(U) = S \cap V$ and $F : U \to S \cap V$ is a homeomorphism and
(ii) the Jacobian $D_uF$ has rank $2$ for every point $u\in U$.

---

My questions is from this definition does it follow that $F$ is a diffeomorphism?
If it is true then how can I prove because here we need to show that $F^{-1}$ is also a smooth map.
otherwise Can anyone give me a counter-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to speak about diffeomorphisms and the smoothness of $F^{-1}$, you need to know what it actually means, because smoothness is usually defined first for maps between open sets in Euclidean spaces.

One way how to endow $S$ with a "differential structure" is the notion of smooth atlas, which is exactly your definition of "regular surface". You can take this as *a definition* of "local diffeomorphism" (more precisely, you can define a map $G:S\cap V\to\mathbb{R}^2$ to be smooth iff $G\circ F: U\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is smooth).

Another way how to define smoothness is to show that there exists a function $G$ from an open neighborhood of $S\cap V$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ which is smooth (in the common sense) and $G|_{S\cap V}=F^{-1}$. Such $G$ really exists.